# working voltage and output levels of a logical gate chip

Tags: logic-gates, inverter, component-selection

I would like to apply some digital gates to control 12V signals. Concretely I would like to invert some of them using this inverter chip [inverters](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1878543.pdf?_ga=2.53782248.1540989914.1564564573-761837274.1564564573&_gac=1.82587108.1564572371.CjwKCAjw-ITqBRB7EiwAZ1c5UxG9F2-EUFXI-hZ0CKCj0Z3g1IifyTFx71qXpTdsnF0N7PPLNzxowxoCZuwQAvD_BwE). But I would like to keep Vout = 12V. Controled device needs Vcontrol = 12V.

I choose gates with Vdd max > 12V in order to keep compliance. But looking at this table on page 3, I can see the Voutput field:

[image: foto]

When I see at its description that minimum voltage was 5V and maximum one is 15V I firstly thought that I could use whatever from 5V to 15V. But looking at the picture it seems only 3 possible Vout = Vdd levels.

questions:

- does it means that I can't input signals with 12V and get Vout = 12V?

Comment: [What method is best used for estimating specification values between those given in the datasheet?](https://e2e.ti.com/support/logic/f/151/t/793508) And [TI's datasheet](http://www.ti.com/document-viewer/CD4069UB/datasheet/typical-characteristics-schs0542493#SCHS0542493) has more information. The voltage drop over the output transistor also depends on the output current; how large is your load?

Answer (score 5):

Most CMOS logic chips have specifications for 5v, 10v, and 15v operation, but you can use them at any voltage inbetween. (Note some "high voltage" CMOS versions can be operated from 20v or so.)

[image: Sample of Inverter Datasheet]
For an inverter like the [MC14060UB](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1878543.pdf), the specifications are condensed into a table. For just these highlighted lines:

- In orange, when the input is "0" or low, the output is 9.0v (guaranteed, perhaps higher.) This is when powered from Vdd=10v. For \$V_{IL}\$, at all temperatures, the maximum input voltage that will be read as a "0" is 2.0v. The typical (note 2) value *"is not to be used for design purposes but is intended as an indication of the IC’s potential performance."* So this chip can *potentially* interpret an input voltage up to 4.5v as a "0".
- In Yellow, when an input is "0", the output is 13.5v or more. This is when powered from Vdd=15v. The maximum guaranteed "0" input level is 2.5v, but it will probably accept 6.75v as a "0" input.

So 12v is slightly less than half the difference between 10v and 15v ratings (12.5v would be exactly half), so a quick interpolation should give you values. i.e., for Vdd=12v, \$V_{IL}\$ should be ~2.2v, with a typical "0" voltage of ~5v.

About CMOS in particular, typically, they operate faster at higher voltages. And they can be powered from less than 5v, but they slow down significantly and nothing is guaranteed.

When using any digital logic chip, always pull unused inputs either high or low. There exists a "no-go" zone between a "high" and "low" input level, where the chip will consume too much power. If any input is left unconnected, they typically float in this zone and even oscillate, destroying the chip.

And some CMOS chips are very static-electricity-sensitive; best to work on a grounded mat with an anti-static wrist strap.

Comment: Are there different CMOS catogary for each voltage level?

Comment: @user_fs10 What do you mean with "category"? All specifications describe the same chip; see the graphs in the TI datasheet.

Comment: Hi @rdtsc, thanks for this explanation. I would like to add the next question to this. Are you saying that through an interpolation, Vin should be 2.2V (low state) if I want to get Vout = 12V when input (Vin)  = '0' logical state? And is it linear interpolation?

Comment: It should be close to linear interpolation. This chip states that for \$V_{DD}\$ of 15v and input low, \$V_O\$ is *guaranteed* to be 13.5v but it could be higher than this. Likewise for \$V_{DD}\$ of 10v, \$V_O\$ will be at least 9.0v. So if you set \$V_{DD}\$ = 12v, \$V_O\$ will be around 11.0v.  If this needs to be exactly 12v, consider using an external transistor or MOSFET.

Answer (score 1):

> does it means that I can't input signals with 12V and get Vout = 12V?

To get 12v output, you need to use a supply voltage of 12V.

Your input signal should be between 10V and 12V to guarantee getting a low output, and between 0V and 2V to guarantee getting a 12v output.

The input voltage should not dwell between 2v and 10v for longer than it needs to. If you do have a slowly changing input signal, perhaps from an RC filter, then you should use a chip with schmidt trigger inputs, that is designed to behave itself with intermediate input levels.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I will be using 12V for VDD and I just need Vout = 12V when Vin = low, in order to be applied to switch control. So, it could be fine for this. I think our input signals doesn't go to be slow. But I will take your suggestion if I find this case. I don't know too much about schmitt trigger inputs. I guess they are used before gate inputs.